# ChangeNotifier not working for collection (List)

Tags: flutter, dart

I use [get_it_mixin](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it_mixin) for state management in my **Flutter** project.

I have a model class which manages a List of objects and its sorting order. The sorting order is just a `String` with the name of the field which should be used to sort.

The UI is a `ListView.separated` which contains a `Slidable`. You can modify, copy or delete an entry in the list. On top of the list is `DropDownButton` which allows to select a field by which the list should be sorted.

Here are the relevant parts of the screen:
[image]

The Widget is *stateless* and has two watchers in the `build` method like so:

```
var ccOverviewList = watchOnly((CcListManager ccListManager) => ccListManager.creditCardOverviewList);
var sortProperty = watchOnly((CcListManager ccListManager) => ccListManager.sortProperty);
```

When the user select a different property to sort the list, I call a method in my model class which then calls `notifyListener`. This works fine for the sorting property sting **but does not work when the list is modified**.
The `onChanged` handler of the `DropDownButton` looks like so:

```
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        GetIt.I<CcListManager>().sortProperty = newValue!;
      },
```

The implementation in the Model (CcListManager):

```
class CcListManager extends ChangeNotifier {
  var _sortProperty = 'Name';
  set sortProperty(String val) {
    _sortProperty = val;
    _sortCreditCardOverview();
    debugPrint('Notifying listeners...');
    notifyListeners();
  }
  String get sortProperty => _sortProperty;

  List<CreditCardOverview> _creditCardOverviewList = /*<CreditCardOverview>*/[];
  set creditCardOverviewList(List<CreditCardOverview> val) {
    _creditCardOverviewList = val;
    debugPrint('Notifying listeners...');
    notifyListeners();
  }
  List<CreditCardOverview> get creditCardOverviewList => _creditCardOverviewList;


}
```

When the `_sortProperty` changes and `notifyListeners` is called, I can see that the `.build()` method of my widget with the ListView is called.

**But when I do ANY modification** on the list `_creditCardOverviewList` the `build()` method is **NOT** called and therefore the List does not update. Here is the code for a `delete` operation:

```
  void removeCreditCardFromOverview(String creditCardId) {
    debugPrint('CcListManager.removeCreditCardFromOverview()');
    var pos = _creditCardOverviewList.indexWhere((element) => element.creditCardLocalId == creditCardId);
    if (pos >= 0) {
      _creditCardOverviewList.removeAt(pos);
      debugPrint('Notifying listeners...');
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

I have no idea why **it works for primitive types** but **not for collections**. To me it looks like inside `notifyListeners()` it checks if the value of the property did really change and somehow does **not** recognise, that the elements of the list or its length have changed and therefore does not notify the registered listeners.

I have also no idea whether it is a problem of `get_it` / `get_it_mixin` plugin or flutters `ChangeNotifier` / `notifyListeners`.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

Ok found the problem myself. It is something people using provider experienced as well more than a year ago.
It looks like `notifyListeners` checks if the value has **really** changed. It looks like they rely on the `==` operator for lists. And this operator does **not** make a deep comparison of every member in the list. So the solution is to re-create the entire list using the `.from()` named constructor. Then it works as expected. So the above code for delete needs to be changed like so:

```
void removeCreditCardFromOverview(String creditCardId) {
    var pos = _creditCardOverviewList.indexWhere((element) => element.creditCardLocalId == creditCardId);
    if (pos >= 0) {
      _creditCardOverviewList.removeAt(pos);
      creditCardOverviewList = List.from(_creditCardOverviewList);
    }
  }
```

`notifyListeners` is called by the setter of `creditCardOverviewList`.